# Exception Type: OperationalError - Exception Value: no such column: blog_article.slug

Tags: python, django, database-migration, slug

I am making a blog using django. I created an app named blog, and in *models.py* I created the following model, for articles on this blog :

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    COUNTRIES = (
        ("fr", "france"),
        ("ge", "germany"),
        )
    nationality = models.CharField(choices= COUNTRIES, max_length = 20)
    publication_date = models.DateTimeField()
    content = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_article', None, { 'slug': self.slug })
```

In *admin.py* I did the following, in order to have the slug prepopulated with the title :

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['posted']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
```

I have ran *python manage.py makemigrations* and *migrate* several times, tried to squash the migrations as I found in other posts here. When I run *makemigrations* I get : "No changes detected". When I run *migrate* I get "No migrations to apply".

However, when I *runserver* and go to the admin interface in order to add a new article, fill the "title" Field, see the slug field filled automatically (due to prepopulation) and want to *SAVE*, here is what I get:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/article/add/

Django Version: 1.9.4
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog.apps.BlogConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  541.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  244.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1437.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  184.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1370.             if form.is_valid():

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  161.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  153.             self.full_clean()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  364.         self._post_clean()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _post_clean
  402.             self.validate_unique()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in validate_unique
  411.             self.instance.validate_unique(exclude=exclude)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in validate_unique
  922.         errors = self._perform_unique_checks(unique_checks)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _perform_unique_checks
  1017.             if qs.exists():

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in exists
  651.             return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in has_results
  501.         return compiler.has_results()

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in has_results
  819.         return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  848.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  323.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

**Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/blog/article/add/
Exception Value: no such column: blog_article.slug**
```

I get the same result if I click on "Article" in the admin interface. I tried to squash the migrations, to makemigrations and migrate again, but it hasn't worked... I looked everywhere and did not find an answer that worked for me -- thank you so much if you can give some tips on this !

Comment: Django version? have you tried `python manage.py makemigrations blog` , `python manage.py migrate blog`?

Comment: Django version is: (1, 9, 4, 'final', 0)
Yes I have tried these commands too but they haven't changed the outcome !

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following?

Check your migrations folder. Let's say you've added Article under `my_project/blog/migrations/0020_...` Then can you try to run:

`./manage.py migrate blog 0019`
=> that should get you an error (blog_article table doesn't exists - cannot be removed)

Then fake it:
`./manage.py migrate blog 0019 --fake`

Then migrate again:
`./manage.py migrate blog`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, I have tried it and it did not work! I had previously deleted all migrations and makemigrations/migrate again, in case something would have been wrong with the migrations folders (and because my app is at the early stage of development, which means I did not mind delete migrations).... Here is what my only migration file looks like (apart from the __init__.py) :

Comment: class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True
    dependencies = [
    ]
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Article',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)),
                ('slug', models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)),
                ('author', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('content', models.TextField()),
            ],
        ),

Comment: OK so it's probably not a migration problem. Can you confirm the table is created with all its columns (using raw SQL)? If you comment out the line with `prepopulated_fields`, what does the admin page look like?

Comment: Maybe in the admin try to explicitly list the fields - instead of using `exclude`.

Comment: Any chance there is a conflict with another "blog" application?

Comment: When I comment out prepopulated_fields, it does not change anything - except that in the admin page, when I enter the title of an article, the slug does not fill itself automatically. There is no possible conflict with another blog application. But it seems that the column "slug" is not created in the database...

Comment: OK so it's not a migration issue then. The slug is there and you can update it (correct?). It sounds like a Django bug.